# Elliptical billiard table - a ball shot from one focus reaching the other focus (proof using $\tan (\theta -\phi)=...$)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

It is known that if there is an elliptical billiard table and we shoot a ball from one focus of the ellipse in any direction, it is necessary that the ball reaches the other focus in only one bounce (or no bounce).

[image]

You can see here that the angles $\beta$ are the same. I wanted to prove this, so using implicit differentiation I calculated the slope of the line F1P (called $l$), the slope of the line F2P (called $m$), and the slope of the line nP (called $n$). Then I got the following formula, for $F_1(-\alpha,0)$ and $F_2(\alpha, 0)$ and $P(x,y)$:

$$l = \frac{y}{x+\alpha}$$
$$m = \frac{a^2}{b^2}\frac{y}{x}$$
$$n = \frac{y}{x-\alpha}$$

I wanted to verify that the both $\beta$ are the same by comparing the tangent values:

$$\frac{m-l}{1+ml} = \tan(\beta) = \frac{n-m}{1+nm}$$

Here I used the formula $$\tan (\theta -\phi)=\frac{\tan(\theta)-\tan(\phi)}{1+\tan(\theta)\tan(\phi)}$$

I put everything into the Computer Algebra System and I get the following result:

$$\frac{\alpha^2(x+a^2)y}{a^2b^2+\alpha^2b^2x} = \frac{-\alpha^2(x-a^2)y}{a^2b^2-\alpha^2b^2x}$$

which is not an identity. This contradicts with the obvious result that we can guarantee (that $\beta$ are the same). What is wrong?

Comment: "in less than one bounce" will be difficult to achieve...

Comment: Your problem is that the slopes of $F_1P$ or the slope of $F_2P$ can be negative as it is the case here for the second one...

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, it's obviously a typo. Sorry for that. Less than or equal to one bounce.

Comment: @JeanMarie Hmm, then how may I generalise this idea? I tried out squaring both sides, but it seems that it doesn't quite help.

Comment: You seem to have some confusion with $m$ and $n$ here. The expressions for slopes you've written have $m$ and $n$ switched, and $\tan\beta$ should have expressions with $m$ and $n$ and with $l$ and $n$, but not one with $m$ and $l$.

Comment: Also, note that $\alpha^2 = a^2 - b^2$, $(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$, and something went wrong with your computer algebra system entry because $x - a^2$ has incompatible units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take an ellipse centered at origin with major semi-axis $a$ and minor semi-axis $b$.

$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$

Focii of ellipse are $F_1 (- \alpha, 0)$ and $F_2 (\alpha, 0)$, where $\alpha^2 = a^2 - b^2$

We take a point $P$ on ellipse as $(a \cos\theta, b \sin\theta)$

Then slopes of lines $PF_1$ and $PF_2$ are,

$m_1 = \dfrac{b \sin \theta - 0}{a \cos\theta + \alpha}, m_2 = \dfrac{b \sin \theta - 0}{a \cos\theta - \alpha}$

Slope of normal line passing through point $P$ is,

$m = \dfrac{a \ sin\theta}{b \cos\theta}$

Now there are two ways to proceed - show that one of the angle bisectors of the lines $PF_1$ and $PF_2$ has the slope $m$. The other way is to show that the angle between normal line and $PF_1$, and the angle between normal line and $PF_2$ are same. I will use the second approach as I think the working is a bit simpler in this approach.

$m - m_1 = \dfrac{a \ sin\theta}{b \cos\theta} - \dfrac{b \sin \theta}{a \cos\theta + \alpha} = \dfrac{(a^2-b^2) \sin \theta \cos\theta + a \alpha \sin \theta}{b \cos\theta (a \cos\theta + \alpha)} = \dfrac{\alpha \sin \theta (a +  \alpha \cos\theta)}{b \cos\theta (a \cos\theta + \alpha)}$

(using $a^2 - b^2 = \alpha^2$)

$1 + m \ m_1 = \dfrac{b ( a + \alpha \cos\theta)}{b \cos\theta (a \cos\theta + \alpha)}$

So angle $\theta_1$ between line going through $P$ and focus $(-\alpha, 0)$, and the normal line at $P$ is given by,

$\tan \theta_1 = \left| \dfrac{m-m_1}{1 + m \ m_1} \right| = \left|\dfrac{\alpha \sin \theta}{b}\right|$

Similarly show that $\tan \theta_2 = \left|\dfrac{\alpha \sin \theta}{b}\right|$

Can you take it from here?

---

Alternate approach: make use of angle bisector theorem ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)). If normal line intersects $F_1F_2$ at point $Q$, show that

$\dfrac{PF_1}{PF_2} = \dfrac{QF_1}{QF_2}$ ...$(i)$

If point $P$ is $(r, s)$, equation of normal line is

$ \displaystyle y - s = \frac{a^2s}{b^2r} (x-r)$ so point $Q$ is $\left (\dfrac{\alpha^2 r}{a^2}, 0\right)$

Now just take distances between points and you can easily show $(i)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Could you please suggest why my method would not work?

Comment: your method is similar to mine but it is not necessary that $\frac{m-l}{1+ml} = \frac{n-m}{1+nm}$. Rather, $\left|\frac{m-l}{1+ml}\right| = \left|\frac{n-m}{1+nm}\right|$.

Comment: An alternate approach - take any point $Q$ where normal line intersects $F_1F_2$. Show that $\frac{PF_1}{PF_2} = \frac{QF_1}{QF_2}$. That will prove that $PQ$ is angle bisector of $\angle F_1 P F_2$.